# Программирование на Arduino

Tags: arduino

Собираюсь заняться программированием на Arduino и хотелось бы узнать у тех, кто умеет, какими ресурсами вы пользовались? Интересуюсь, так как в интернете много мусора.

Comment: Рекомендую обратиться вот к этой [справке](http://playground.arduino.cc//Russian/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с предыдущим ответом. 
Дополнительно могу посоветовать на русском языке [Амперку](http://amperka.ru). Продают и держат неплохую базу знаний.